# Insert text and then merge pdf

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I'm using IText7 version 7.0.2.2, I'm new with it, I'm trying to merge several pdfs at the same time into one that I'm uploading first, that is working fine, the problem is when I try dynamically to insert some text in one of the pdfs and then merge it, I'm using PdfWriter to write some content into the pdf and then try to merge it, but I'm getting this exception: `'Cannot copy indirect object from the document that is being written.`

This is some of the code I'm using:

```
private byte[] MergePdfForms( HttpPostedFileBase firstPdf, List<SectionAndPdfs> sectionsAndPdf)
        {
var dest = new MemoryStream();
            PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(dest));
            PdfMerger merger = new PdfMerger(pdf);
firstSourcePdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(keyValuePair.Value), new PdfWriter(dest));
Document document = new Document(firstSourcePdf);
document.Add(new Paragraph(sectionsAndPdf[i].Key).SetBackgroundColor(iText.Kernel.Colors.Color.GRAY)); 

merger.Merge(firstSourcePdf, 1, subPages); //I'm getting the exception here..
firstSourcePdf.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug in the class PdfDestination. It was fixed, and will be present in our next release. At the moment you can of course use the snapshot release, which should solve the problem.

Comment: Where do I get the snapshot release?

Comment: The snapshot release can be found in our repository  
https://repo.itextsupport.com/webapp/#/artifacts/browse/tree/General/files

Or simply change the version (assuming you're using Maven or Nugget) to the snapshot version.

Comment: I am running 7.0.4 in Java. Is this still an issue? I'm getting the exact same error doing something every similar.